# Display certain page if a button is clicked and not when typed in address bar

Tags: php, payment

I was wondering if there was a way to only display a page if a button from a previous page was clicked? For instance, I want users to pay to view articles on my site, but they could bypass everything by simply entering the url of the article they wanted to read

My question was, is there an ifset in place that would require a button to be clicked prior to being opened? (If you have a better solution for a payment method that would display certain pages I would be open to those too...justsaying)

Comment: some real security implementations will need to be made there

Comment: The payments would be a page controlled by paypal...so im not worried about the security on that part. My main issue is trying to display the page only if the payment has been made

Comment: I'd recommend a good book on ecommerce and php, sounds like you're unfamiliar with a lot of important concepts and one answer here won't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to think (and study) how secure sites are implemented. This is more complicated than just differentiating between a button click and a page load. The way this can be done (in very rough terms) in web development is by having the user be redirected to a secure URL first where they are identified as a user who is allowed to have access, and if so, they are then redirected to your protected content.

**Edit:**

After seeing your comment that you are handling payment with PayPal, not much of what I said changes, but I think you should focus your study on PayPal integration. There are a lot of good resources online for that for people with little to no experience developing websites.

Comment: What if I had them access a secure payment page (ie PayPal) and had them redirected from there? Is there a way to randomize the url so its never the same thing?

Comment: PayPal will always redirect you to the same place, but I think they send valuable data along with it like a transaction id and what not. You can then use the transaction id to validate the transaction. e.g. if it's a valid transaction id that hasnt been used before then show the protected content.

Comment: Thats what I was kind of thinking but actually implementing that would be difficult (atleast for my skill level) but Id be willing to try

Answer (score 0):

You can't really solve this in the browser, it needs to be solved through login or similar action on the web server. There are several CMSes (Content Management Systems, web server software for serving content) with available plugins for commercial access. I would recommend wordpress.org, joomla.org or drupal.org

Or, if you are less technically inclined, take a look at hosted solutions like squarespace.com and equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a form that does a `POST` to the page containing the document, setting a variable. In the page serving the document, you check if `$_POST['var_name']` is set and serve the page acordingly.

Or, you could use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and only let authenticated users to see the documents they paid for